# MongoDB Aggregation Challenge

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

I am new to MongoDB. I started to study MongoDB 2 months ago. So I can do CRUD operation.
But now I am having trouble in using aggregation.

Let me explain my problem.

I have two collections (users, foods).
users { _id: "...", favouriteFoods: ["...", "...", "...",...] }
foods { _id: "...", name: "..." }.

I want to get the list of foods which has favourited user.
So output is like this.
Favourited_Foods [
_id: "...",
name: "...",
numberOfFavourites: 4,
]

Anyone who is expert in MongoDB Aggregation, please help me.
Thank you.

I tried to use $lookup pipeline to perform this action.
But As I said I am new to MongoDB.
So I couldn't do this for 3 days.

Comment: Please provide valid sample json documents. Currently the masked sample in the question is unclear for illustrating the expected behvaiour.

Answer (score 0):

I did this myself. I'd like to help anyone who has same task with me.
Let me add the result.

```
db.gigs.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "likedGigs",
        as: "liked_users"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        numberOfLikes: { $size: "$liked_users" }
    }
},
{
    $skip: 3
},
{
    $limit: 2
},
{
    $match: { numberOfLikes: { $gt: 0 } }
}
])
```

Comment: This answer may be correct but its helpful to include why this answer solves the questioner's problem, instead of just posting a plain code solution.